# Comparing Variable to Ints with if/fi in BASH script

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare the $duration variable to an int, to see how long it is. I need to deturmine how many 0's to append to the file name to maintain clean names e.g.

cap_000001.png

cap_002938.png

My current statement is:

```
if [ $duration < 1000 ]; then
    sudo ./v2u cap_000$duration.png
    echo 1000 seconds
fi
if [ $duration < 100 ]; then
    sudo ./v2u cap_0000$duration.png
    echo 100 seconds
fi
if [ $duration < 10 ]; then
    sudo ./v2u cap_00000$duration.png
    echo 10 seconds
fi
```

Thanks for Helping!

If someone has an easier solution for naming the files with a consistent number of digits that would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `man printf`. It is far, far better for this task than a bunch of `if` blocks.

```
sudo ./v2u $(printf "cap_%06d.png" "$duration")
```

Comment: Agree that it's a much more superior solution. +1. I wrote a direct answer to the OP's question too, as well a fully-spelt-out version of your approach. I hope you won't mind. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question about comparing numbers:

```
if [ "$duration" -lt 1000 ]; then
```

You get the idea. :-)

Amber's answer is, of course, much better from a forest-instead-of-trees point of view:

```
printf "cap_%06d.png" "$duration"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use comparison operators such as `>` instead of `-lt`, Bash does numeric comparisons like this:

```
if (( duration < 1000 )); then
```

However, `printf` is the way to go.

This will give a similar affect to the `printf` approach, also without having to do any `if` statements:

```
num=000000$duration
sudo ./v2u "cap_${num: -6}.png"
```